# How to install Microsoft font on Freya?

Tags: software-installation, fonts

Is there any way to install microsoft fonts (Arial,Times New Roman...) using `apt-get` on Freya?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just try this on your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```